# Magento 1 - How to get relevant 'tax_calculation_rate_id' from order items

Tags: magento-1.9, taxes

I'm trying to get 'tax_calculation_rate_id' by iterating through ordered products.

The following code works ok, but the problem arises when there are multiple ids assigned to the same percentage values (e.g. "VAT exempt rate" at 0% and "EC Sales rate" at 0%)

Is there a better way to get the rate ids calculated?

Thank you for your help!

```
// $line_item and $address come as arguments 

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$product_class= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->loadByAttribute('sku',$line_item->getSku())
                         ->getTaxClassId();
$tax_model = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
$request = $tax_model->getRateRequest($address, null, null, $store);
$percent = $tax_model->getRate($request->setProductClassId($product_class));

$rates = Mage::getModel("tax/calculation_rate")
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addFieldToFilter('rate', array('eq'=>$percent));
foreach ($rates as $rate)
{  
    $mage_rate_id = $rate->getTaxCalculationRateId();
    // if more than 1 rate exits it obviously picks the last one
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you will need to get the dedicated tax rates not only by percentage but also by code.
I would say you can to call `$tax_model->getAppliedRates($request->setProductClassId($product_class))` instead of `$tax_model->getRate($request->setProductClassId($product_class))`.
With that call you will get an array with all rates -  but as far as I see the tax_calculation_rate_id is not in this array (for what ever reason).
Therfore you will need to get the rates with an additional call to `$tax_model->getRates($ruleId)`.

I suppose the code for that would look like this - but I haven't tested it:

```
$tax_model = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
$request = $tax_model->getRateRequest($address, null, null, $store);
$appliedRates = $tax_model->getAppliedRates($request->setProductClassId($product_class));

foreach ($appliedRates as $appliedRate){
    foreach ($appliedRate['rates'] as $oneRate){
        //returns an array of all applied rate ids
        $rates = $tax_model->getRates($oneRate['rule_id']);
    }
}
```

Anyway, I quess alternatively you can get all the data you need by using the following 3 tables: `sales_order_tax_item`, `sales_order_tax` and `tax_calculation_rate`.
Each order item has entries for each applied tax rate in `sales_order_tax_item`, therefore you just need to consider the corresponding rows in that table.
This should work, if you have unique codes for your tax rates.

```
//assuming your parameter $line_item is an order item you can load the entries 
//for that order item from sales_order_tax_item table
$taxItemCollection = Mage::getModel('tax/sales_order_tax_item')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', array('eq'=>$line_item->getId()));

//iterate through the collection items and load the corresponding sales_order_tax entry
//and based on that the corresponding tax_calculation_rate entry
foreach ($taxItemCollection as $taxItem) {
    $tax = Mage::getModel('tax/sales_order_tax')->load($taxItem->getTaxId());
    $rate = Mage::getModel("tax/calculation_rate")-loadByCode($tax->getCode());
    $mage_rate_id = $rate->getTaxCalculationRateId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They both work but only if the tax rate is more than 0.

Comment: I might need to implement an if statement and add an algorithm to handle 0% cases.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's strange. The first approach `$tax_model->getAppliedRates()` just joins the tables `tax_calculation`, `tax_calculation_rule`, `tax_calculation_rate` and gets the corresponding data whitout taking care of the percentage of the rate. I would suggest to dump the array `$appliedRates` and see what's inside. If you don't see the data there, check the generated SQL in `Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation::getCalculationProcess()`

Comment: You are right. $appliedRates is empty if there's no relevant tax rule set up.
Thank you every so much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what cases there are more than one [rates] in the $appliedRates array?  If there's always one rate wouldn't that be easier to access it by $appliedRates[0]['rates'][0]['rule_id'], or by $appliedRates[0]['id'] and then addFieldToFilter('tax_calculation_rate_id', array('eq'=>$id)); ?

Comment: From the stores I worked with I don't know any case with more than one rate for a product but I would not exclude that there are such situations depending on tax laws in other countries. But be aware you get the rule id not the rate id in `$appliedRates` and therefore you will have to call `getRates` based on the rule id.